# Flyway on Sybase ASE results in Invalid colum name error when there are double quotes in the SQL Statement

Tags: flyway, sap-ase

flyway migrate command on Sybase ASE returns an error when there is double quotes in the SQL statement.

```
Migration R__wes.sql failed
---------------------------
SQL State  : 42S22
Error Code : 207
Message    : Invalid column name 'C'.
Statement  : SELECT count(1) from redemptions WHERE redem_type = "C"
```

I'm using Flyway 6.3.3 on linux and tried with both jConnect and jTDS drivers.

Simple solution is to replace the double quotes with singles. 
However I have hundreds of complex stored procedures that will need to be updated so they will work with flyway.

Is there something I missed that would resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Wesley

Comment: You need to replace with single quotes.  If there be some pattern of usage here, maybe someone can suggest a general replacement solution.

Comment: I'm assuming from your comment - *I have hundreds of complex stored procedures* - that you've successfully run these procs with double-quoted values for some time now... and that Flyway is 'new' in your environment, yes?  Regardless, in ASE if you issue `set quoted_identifier on` (at the session level) then you should be able to use double-quoted values.  I'm guessing whatever you were using before Flyway, there was a config setting to ensure `set quoted_identifier on` was issued at connect time; does Flyway have a similar config/setting when initiating a db connection?

Comment: Mark - Your assumption is correct. The stored procs are already in the database. Flyway will be used to migrate future changes to existing stored procs.

Comment: Mark - flyway has callback beforeMigrate where I can set the quoted_identifier to off.  That seems to do the trick. Will test more before..   I also found this too : https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1355

Comment: ah, yes, I misread the question ... `set quoted_identifer off` (not `on`) would be the correct setting; anyhoo, sounds like you're past this issue ... onto the next :-)

Answer (score 1):

With Mark's suggestion i was able to resolve this issue by adding

`set quoted_identifier off` in beforeMigrate.sql (flyway callback) to disable sybase to treat strings as identifiers

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315903.htm

Thank you all!